# Beanstalkd - Multiple worker accessing the same queue

Tags: beanstalkd

I would like to use Beanstalkd in my deployment process. The idea is similar to one that IGN uses (https://github.com/ign/brood). At any given time I may want to trigger two clients to download the latest code and restart Apache. Is it possible to have multiple workers (one on each client) process the same queue? As a workaround I could create a queue for each client.

Answer (score 0):

A specific queue for each client, used for commands for that client. Have them all listen on their own queue, and send a simple 'RESTART' message to as many of the clients as required.

I'd have a bash script that started the job, and kept it running perform the actual restarting. You script would only need to

1. delete the 'RESTART' message (otherwise it will get the same message next time)
2. `exit(90);` the script

The return value is picked up by the Bash script, and the action is performed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# runBeanstalkd-worker.sh

# a shell script that keeps looping until an exit code is given
# if it does an exit(0), restart after a second - or if it's a declared error
# if we've restarted in a planned fashion, we don't bother with any pause
# and for one particular code, exit the script entirely.
# The numbers 97, 98, 99 must match what is returned from the PHP script

nice php -q -f ./cli-beanstalk-worker.php -- $@
ERR=$?

## Possibilities
# 90    - restart apache
# 97    - planned pause/restart
# 98    - planned restart
# 99    - planned stop, exit.
# 0     - unplanned restart (as returned by "exit;")
#        - Anything else is also unplanned paused/restart

# 90    - restart apache
if [ $ERR -eq 90 ]
then
   service apache restart
   sleep 5;
   exec $0 $@;
fi

if [ $ERR -eq 97 ]
then
   # a planned pause, then restart
   echo "97: PLANNED_PAUSE - wait 1";
   sleep 1;
   exec $0 $@;
fi

####   other actions, like planned-restart, or shutdown

# unplanned exit, pause, and restart
echo "unplanned restart: err:" $ERR;
echo "sleeping for 1 sec"
sleep 1

exec $0 $@
```